# Notes missing after upgrade to iOS 10

Tags: notes.app, ios

I just upgraded my iPhone 6 to IOS 10 and half of my notes are missing. I have a few notes under the cloud, gmail, and my phone but nothing is showing up under my email (not sure if notes were ever there).

Seems any note created or edited in the past 12 months are gone. I have already restarted the phone.

Comment: Did you make a backup before you upgraded? Also, if you go on iCloud.com are any of the missing notes there?

Comment: Sadly, no I did not make a backup. Lesson learned. I checked my old phone, without a SIM, and done of the missing notes are still on that phone. Does that mean the missing notes are hidden somewhere on my phone? The missing notes on my old phone were listed under my email. On my new phone their are no notes available. I did check the cloud but nothing new was there. Thanks

Comment: When you say "listed under your email" I'm not sure what you mean. What kind of email account (iCloud, Gmail, etc)?

Comment: I mean my personal email. I have notes saved to iCloud, gmail, my iPhone and (on the old phone), my personal email.

Comment: Okay I think I might be misunderstanding you then. Were any notes in the app called Notes on your iPhone before you upgraded? And are those the ones that are gone?

Comment: Yes, there were notes in local notes before I upgraded. Some are still there and some are gone. Comparing my notes to my old phone (I switched over a year ago) it seems I'm mostly missing the notes that were tied to my personal, not gmail, email account.

Comment: Is it possible they're on that personal server hiding in a folder somewhere? Is that personal account still listed under Settings > Notes > Accounts?

Comment: yes, the personal account is still listed under Settings > Notes > Accounts.  And now I can create a note in my phone app and it will appear on the web client in a folder called notes.  I'm chatting with rackspace now to see if they  restore my email from before this upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't backup the notes with iTunes or iCloud, then they are gonna permanently. On iPhone, there are two different kinds of notes: one is synced with iCloud and the other is local notes. I am aware of this after switching to a new iPhone. I guess the missing notes were stored locally.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you visit www.icloud.com and verify that your notes are present there. If it isnt there then its likely that you have notes being saved to an email that you either currently have, or used to have.

If neither is present, check iCloud settings on your iPhone for iCloud backups and check iTunes for iOS backups and see if you have a backup that existed before you updated. If you have one, then you can restore it and then try to see if the notes come back.